# New JDBC index not appearing in Kibana's Discover data view

Tags: logstash, kibana, elk, logstash-jdbc

I added the below config to my `conf.d/logstash-simple.conf` file.

```
input {
    beats {
        jdbc {
        add_field => { "[index_name]" => "pglogdb" }
        add_field => { "[@metadata][beat]" => "jdbc" }
        add_field => { "[@metadata][version]" => "1.1" }
        tags => ["pglogdb_data"]
        #jdbc_driver_library => ""
        jdbc_driver_class => "Java::org.postgresql.Driver"
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:postgresql://1.6.2.13:5432/pgmessagesuat"
        jdbc_user => "pguat"
        jdbc_password => "password"
        last_run_metadata_path => "/etc/logstash/conf.d/lastrun/.logstash_jdbc_pgmessagesuat_last_run"
        schedule => "0,10,20,30,40,50 * * * *"
        statement => "SELECT QUERY"
        use_column_value => true
        tracking_column => "a.transaction_timestamp"
        tracking_column_type => "timestamp"
    }
    ...
    filter {
        if 'pglogdb_data' in [tags] {
            mutate {
                add_field => { "[index_name]" => "pglogdb" }
            }
        }
    }
    ...
    output {
        if ('' in [index_name]) {
            elasticsearch {
                user => "logstash_input"
                password => "password"
                hosts => ["https://localhost:9200"]
                manage_template => false
                index => "%{[index_name]}"
                ssl_certificate_verification => false
                        cacert => "/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca.crt"
                ssl => true
        } else {
            elasticsearch {
                user => "logstash_input"
                password => "password"
                hosts => ["https://localhost:9200"]
                manage_template => false
                index => "%{[@metadata][indexname]}-%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{[@metadata][version]}-%{+YYYY.MM-'w'ww}"
                ssl_certificate_verification => false
 
                        cacert => "/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca.crt"
                ssl => true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After making the update I ran `systemctl restart logstash`. When I then went into Discover in Kibana I was unable to see pglogdb in the data view dropdown.

Why is this? Have I missed something?